Research Mailing Lists / Usenet groups
For Category theory there is a well known and quite active research mailing list like this one.
Do similar mailing lists or usenet groups exist for other branches of mathematics? For example in metric geometry, conformal geometry,...
Or do most research related discussions now take place on MO?

Off-topic here; voted to move to meta.

@YCor How can I move it to meta?

I'm not sure you can (but you can erase and repost, which is fine for the moment since there's no answer or interesting comment). In meta you should find a more focussed tag.

@ycor ok, will do that then

This is the comment I gave on Meta: "What exactly is a "research mailing list"? Most lists I know contain mostly announces of conferences, books, open positions; would those qualify? Or do you expect members to ask and answer questions with mathematical content, like here on MO?". But I doubt OP will reply, since they are inactive from 2017.

Here is a link to the corresponding post on meta: Mailing lists / Usenet groups for research math. (It was recently closed. But this question on the main site has now some close votes, too and i sin the close votes review queue.)

There is a fairly active list of this sort in Foundations of Mathematics (FoM) that used to be run by Martin Davis who passed away last year.  Some of the most active participants are also active here :-)
